# Determining if a set is a generating set for $R^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have

\begin{bmatrix}
       -1 & 0 & 3 & -5           \\[0.3em]
       1 & -1 & -7 & 7 \\[0.3em]
       2 & 2 & 2 & 6
     \end{bmatrix}

and I need to prove if it is a generating set. I have a list of rules that need to be satisfied for it to be true so I go through them one at a time.

The span of the colums of A is $R^m$ where m is the rows of a. This seems to be correct just by looking at it.

Ax=b where A is the matrix, basically that the matrix has a solution. I find the row echelon form and I can see that this is true.

The next three rules can be combined (I think) to say that the rank of the matrix is m from $R^m$ which appears to be true, I verify with wolfram alpha and I am correct that there are 3 pivot colums.

So the book gives the answer that no this is not a generating set, where did I go wrong in my assumptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convince yourself that the rank of the matrix is $2$, not $3$ by adding the first row to the second and by adding the double of the first row to the third.

Congratulations! You have proved that Wolfram's developers did something wrong:$$-4\begin{pmatrix}-1\\0\\3\\-5\end{pmatrix}-2\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\\-7\\7\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}2\\2\\2\\6\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: I don't follow, the rank is not 2 according to wolfram apha

Comment: Congratulations! You have proved that Wolfram's developers did something wrong:$$-4\begin{pmatrix}-1\\0\\3\\-5\end{pmatrix}-2\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\\-7\\7\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}2\\2\\2\\6\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Oh I see now, thank you.